# Django Rest Framework - common nested serializer for multiple models with the same base class

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an abstract model that is used by many inheriting classes. I would like to write a generic serializer that will work universally for all these classes and will only return fields that are common to all these models.

In a simplified version - assuming that I have the following models:

```py
from django.db import models

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    field_a = models.TextField()
    field_b = models.IntegerField()
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class ModelA(BaseModel):
    some_relation = models.ForeignKey(
        "app.RelatedModelA", 
        related_name="model_a_set", 
        ...
    )

class ModelB(BaseModel):
    different_relation = models.ForeignKey(
        "app.RelatedModelB", 
        related_name="model_b_set", 
        ...
    )

class RelatedModelA(models.Model):
    pass

class RelatedModelB(models.Model):
    pass
```

I would like to be able to define serializers in the following way:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class RelatedModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model_a_set = BaseModelSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = RelatedModelA
        fields = ("id", "model_a_set")

class RelatedModelBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model_b_set = BaseModelSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = RelatedModelB
        fields = ("id", "model_b_set")
```

So the question is - how to define `BaseModelSerializer`? I found a solution that takes into account overriding `to_representation`, although it requires writing serializers for each type separately (`ModelASerializer` and `ModelBSerializer`), so it would look like this:

```py
class BaseModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, ModelA):
            return ModelASerializer(obj, context=self.context).to_representation(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, ModelB):
           return ModelBSerializer(obj, context=self.context).to_representation(obj)

        raise NotImplementedError

    class Meta:
        model = BaseModel
        fields = ("id", "field_a", "field_b")
```

The ideal solution for me would be something like that, without defining serializers for `ModelA` and `ModelB`:

```py
class BaseModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BaseModel
        fields = ("id", "field_a", "field_b")
```

but unfortunately it won't work that way, because an abstract model cannot be set in `Meta`. Is it possible to solve this somehow in a clear way, without defining `ModelASerializer` and `ModelBSerializer` explicitly?

Comment: Why do you use `BaseModel` in a `ModelSerializer`? Abstract model's only purpose is to share common elements to the child classes without creating a table in the database. This, plus, I'm almost certain that this technique raises a `ValueError` in rest framework since you cannot use abstract model's in ModelSerializer.

Comment: I've edited the question - perhaps I should give more context at first. To answer the questions - I'm using `BaseModel` in a `ModelSerializer` because I want to create a model serializer which will be working for all classes derived from `BaseModel` - and yes, I know it'll raise an error - that's why I want to ask for help with solution for this issue, and to find some workaround at least (without defining serializers for each child class)